# How To Automatically Generate Invoice Number In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I automatically generate invoice number based on the company name and the date?
As an example Please see this:
[image: Photo Example]
So how can I get this invoice No:
W: the first letter from the company name
C: the second letter from the company name
Also, if the company name has 3 words, I want to get the first 3 litters as well.
29: day
10: month
18: year

So, Is there a way to get that?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then edit your question so it does not get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to be limited to a maximum of three letters for the company name, you can use a formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(B3,1),MID(B3,FIND(" ",B3)+1,1),IFERROR(MID(B3,FIND(" ",B3,FIND(" ",B3)+1)+1,1),""),TEXT(H3,"DDMMYY"))
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much